# Implementation of Streaming Join in Flink

Tags: inner-join, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am looking at the various implementations of join in Flink. In batch mode, I have come across the `hybrid-hash join` and `sort-merge join`. In both cases, there is a blocking shuffling that is done before the join and hence the output of the operators before join are materialized to some non-ephemeral storage as is said [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/datastream/execution_mode/).

I am now looking at the stream join case. I have seen an implementation where two hash tables are made for the two inputs. Whenever an input comes it is saved in its hash table and also probed against the other hash tables to produce results. To limit the hash table sizes, we put a window for which an input is saved in the hash table. My first question is:

```
Do all stream join cases have this requirement of a window?
```

Specifically, I want to discuss the implementation of the join where a large static `customers` table is joined with an `Orders` stream. In my opinion, the physical implementation should be something like this:

[image: Hybrid hash join]

The `customers` table is first hash-partitioned. Then, the `orders` stream starts flowing in. As the execution mode is `streaming`, the `orders` table is directly sent to join tasks without any materialization.

Does flink have such a join or can I implement this in Flink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's exactly how it is implemented for `BATCH`.

In `STREAMING` you don't have the full Customers table in full, as by definition it is infinite.

For `BATCH`, I'll just quote this [post from their official blog](https://flink.apache.org/news/2019/02/13/unified-batch-streaming-blink.html):

> Flink has streaming runtime operators for many operations, but also specialized operators for bounded inputs [...] The batch join can read one input fully into a hash table and then probe with the other input. The stream join needs to build tables for both sides, because it needs to continuously process both inputs

This link also has information on input size: it can spill to the disk. Windowing is not required (but if you specify it, it will for sure help you maintain performance/deployment size requirements )

---

Now if you're in `STREAMING` mode and know that one side won't change, you can still tell Flink about it so it optimizes around that. [Use `JOIN <table> FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF <table>.{ proctime | rowtime }` for that effect](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/zh/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/joins/#event-time-temporal-join):

> Temporal joins take an arbitrary table (left input/probe site) and correlate each row to the corresponding row’s relevant version in the versioned table (right input/build side)

However be aware that these probe side request will go right through Flink and look it up in the database if you're using JDBC (make sure you have an index on the join key)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Temporal join is kind of similar to the case that I am describing. Any idea, if hybrid hash-join can be used to implement this in Flink, if the static table is huge? Specifically, what I want to know is, can this join be implemented (or is it implemented) in two phases - first a blocking build partitioning, then a streaming pipelined probe. I know I am being too specific, but please bear with me.

Comment: Well, the static table cannot be bigger than what you can spill to disk. Hybrid-has-join is a very low level construct though, and Flink chooses what to do in its execution plan. More details: https://flink.apache.org/news/2015/03/13/peeking-into-Apache-Flinks-Engine-Room.html. If you want to look at the internals, look for HashJoinBuildFirstProperties and HINT_LOCAL_STRATEGY_HASH_BUILD_FIRST (which you might force the optimizer to use) in the code base

Comment: thanks for going into the details. I did go through the link you mentioned but it only talks about `DataSet` and not `DataStream`. I guess what I want to ask is that is a `hyrbrid hash join where the build table first comes in and then probe phase starts` even allowed by Flink in streaming case? Because if the build side is also infinite, then it won't finish. Or is it that I can force flink to use hash-join even for streaming case.

Comment: Also, to reiterate, I want to solve the big build table problem by partitioning it before the probe table comes. Let's assume it fits into memory after partitioning.

Comment: Well then Flink's optimizer should have no problem coming up with the right plan for that. Partitioning/shuffling will already have been decided on by the runtime.